# Blank page when deploying React website on Netlify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, react-router, babeljs

I'm trying to deploy my personal website using React but it's showing a blank page with the following error on the React imports. It works fine on a local host. I've wasted an entire day trying to solve it but with no success. Any ideas on what might be the issue? Thanks in advance.

Error: "Unexpected identifier 'React'. import call expects exactly one argument" on first line

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

// import injectGlobal helper
import { injectGlobal } from 'styled-components';

import Main from './app/Main';

// Global style
injectGlobal`
  html,



body,
  #app,
  .wrapper {
    min-height: 100vh;
    height: 100%;
  }

  html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 100%;
  }

  * {
    &,
    &::after,
    &::before {
      box-sizing: inherit;
    }
  }

  body {
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
     font: 1rem / 1.414 Roboto;
   }
`

const wrapper = document.getElementById('app')

const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Main />
  </BrowserRouter>
)

ReactDOM.render(<App />, wrapper)
```

Comment: Added code as requested

Comment: What URL is your production site on? If it has a base path, e.g. the start page is `https://example.com/mysite/`, then you need to set a [`basename`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string) to `basename="/mysite"` on the `BrowserRouter`. Also, have you compiled your `src` files into a single `bundle.js`?

Comment: @Tholle Where do I write the basename? And I did not make a bundle.js. How can I do that?

Comment: Follow the link in my comment and you will see an example usage. What development environment are you using? If you are using e.g. Create React App you can run `npm run build` and put the resulting `build` folder on your production server.

Comment: @Tholle Thank you for the reply. I did not use create-react-app but still works with `npm run build`. I'm going to take a look at `basename` and I'll keep you posted.

Comment: @Tholle I tried using `<BrowserRouter basename="/"/>` on my Main.js file but to no avail. Still getting a blank page. Any idea on why the server isn't recognizing the imports? Maybe something to do with .babelrc file or package.json?

Comment: `basename="/"` is the default. I might have misunderstood you and thought your site was at `example.com/start_page`. Then you should use `basename="/start_page"`. But if you just have a site like `example.com` you don't need it.

Comment: @Tholle Thank you for your help. I figured it out and it had nothing to do with my code. It was simply a matter of specifying within Netlify the name of the folder on which the build is located. I had it set to `src` and changing it to `dist` solved it.